# & is allowed in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

& is allowed in XML?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, but only at the beginning of a character entity, for example `&gt;` (and in some special cases, such as inside CDATA sections). If you need a literal `&` character, use `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, encode it as `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

No. Use `&amp;` instead.